# Run Heroku Bash Command 7/24

Tags: heroku

I have to open the Heroku bash and type "node main.js" to run my app. But when I close my browser the script stops. How can I run the script 24/7?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be new to heroku, [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#scale-the-app) should help

In your package.json file mention a start script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js",
     ...
}
```

(If you don't have a package.json make sure to run `npm init -y` and commit this file)

And to scale(run) your app:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Your heroku app should automatically be detected as a node application and it would run the start script upon starting

To see the logs and debug, do:

```
heroku logs --tail --num=10
```

and then try visiting your app with the terminal open to see live logs

If you have further problems, make sure to include your logs **without any credentials possibly leaked**